# Почему браузер выдаёт ошибку после того как gulp скомпилировал файл?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, компиляция, минификация

Подключаю библиотеку через libs.js (gulp --> libs.min.js) как положено (

```
@@include('../libs/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js')
```

до этого тоже подключены, работают нормально). После чего браузер выдаёт

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
at libs.min.js:1
```

.
Подключаю напрямую через html - работает.